# почему выводит первое слово с новой строки?

Tags: c

программа выводит предложения в обратном порядке, но первое слово всегда выводится на отдельной строке как это исправить? И для чего нужен & в printf ?

```
#define SIZE 80
void reverse(char b[]);
int main()
{
    char sentence[SIZE];
    printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    fgets(sentence,SIZE, stdin);
    reverse(sentence);
    return 0;
}
void reverse(char b[])
{
  int length= strlen(b), i;
  for(i = length-1; i>= 0; i--)
  {
      if(b[i] == ' '){
        b[i]= '\0';
        printf("%s", &(b[i])+1);
      }
  }
  printf("%s", b);
}
```

Вывод:

```
Enter a sentence: hello world
world
hello
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что функция `fgets` включает замыкающий символ `\n` в прочитанную строку. Вы его не удаляете, считаете частью последнего слова и выводите вместе с этим словом.

---

> И для чего нужен & в printf

Для того же, для чего он нужен где угодно: для получения указателя на что-то.

Comment: а как удалить \n

Comment: Вам не `\n` надо удалять, а скорее пропускать вообще *все* пробельные символы перед очередным словом. А то у вас обычный пробел на конце строки приведет к тому, что там будет "находиться" невидимое слово нулевой длины.